# UIViewController view's frame changes after present(viewController: animated: completion: )

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that I set its size in `ViewDidLoad` like that:

```
//Setting view's frame
let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 10
let height = (43 * UIScreen.main.bounds.height) / 100 //%43 of the screen
self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 80, width: width, height: height)
```

It works great until I try to present another `ViewController` like that:

```
//Presenting AutoCompleteVC
self.autocompleteVC = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
self.autocompleteVC.delegate = self
self.present(self.autocompleteVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

After I dismiss this view (`self.autocompleteVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`) the frame of the first `ViewController`'s view changes to the full screen's frame.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: you can change the set size from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear` to make it do the setting everytime it appear, for the problem, the UIScreen may got updated to original when u present new vc

Comment: You shouldn't be setting your own frame inside the view controller. Please explain in details what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Kamil.S Why not? I need to set the view's size to be smaller

Comment: That's fine, but it shouldn't be that view controller's responsibility. If you want to resize the view using the "oldschool" way with frames (opposed to  autolayout) you should do this in didLayoutSubviews of the parent view controller , not in "self" vc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your frame in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. The frame is already known then. Like this:

```
public override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

   //Setting view's frame
   let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 10
   let height = (43 * UIScreen.main.bounds.height) / 100 //%43 of the screen
   self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 80, width: width, height: height)
}
```

Comment: You are not guaranteed to have frames properly set before the actual layout happens. This is not a good solution

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I am using a custom view controller transition class which is great, but whenever I present a new view on top of it, the parent view moves up. Your solution fixed my problem, thanks again 

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that write your code in viewWillAppear but after set frame, you should write 
`self.view.setNeedsLayout()`

I hope this will work.

Answer (score -1):

The main view of a view controller is positioned and sized by system logic depending on landscape/portrait, splitscreen, modal display, view controller containment...

Instead you should do every content layouting in subviews (depending on main view size) and set background color of the main view to UIColor.clear. 
So in your case add a subview and configure it as you wish.

Hint: You should do it with auto layout instead of manipulating the frame.